# Lua type function for nested table reference

Tags: dynamic, lua, lua-table

I'm just starting to write Lua code for World of Warcraft.  I frequently need to check to see if a global variable nested in a table has been defined by another author's Lua code.
Example:

`Mytable[MyfirstLvl].Mysecondlvl.fred`   where the variable `MyfirstLvl1` has spaces in it

At present I'm using:

```
if (type(Mytable) == 'table') and (type(Mytable[MyfirstLvl]) == 'table') and (type(Mytable[MyfirstLvl].Mysecondlvl) == 'table') then
    --some code using Mytable[MyfirstLvl].Mysecondlvl.fred
end
```

I'd like an easier way to do this.  I thought of writing a function that uses `_G`, but can't find any examples of parsing dynamic variable names that have `'['` and `']'` in them.

Is there an easy way to tell if a value nested several levels down in a table has been defined or can someone help with creating a custom function to do this?

Here is what I came up with:

```
function newType(reference)
    if type(reference) ~= 'string' then
        print('...argument to Type must be a string')
        return
    end

    local t = {string.split('].[', reference)}

    local tt = {}
    for k, v in ipairs(t) do
        if string.len(v) ~= 0 then
            local valueToInsert = v
            if (string.sub(v, 1, 1) == '"') or (string.sub(v, 1, 1) == "'") then
                valueToInsert = string.sub(v, 2, -2)
            elseif tonumber(v) then
                valueToInsert = tonumber(v)
            end
            table.insert(tt, valueToInsert)
        end
    end

    local myReference = _G
    local myType
    for i, curArg in ipairs(tt) do
        if type(myReference) ~= 'table' then            
            return 'nil'            
        end
        if type(myReference[curArg]) ~= 'nil' then
            myReference = myReference[curArg]
            myType = type(myReference)
        else
            return 'nil'
        end
    end
    return myType

end    
SavedDB = {}
SavedDB.profiles = {}
SavedDB.profiles.Character = {}
SavedDB.profiles.Character.name = 'fireymerlin'
print(newType('SavedDB.profiles["Character"].name')
```

All of your comments helped me think this through.  Thank you.  If you see a better way to accomplish this (I hope the example at the bottom helps), please let me know.  I was trying to make a function that I could pass one string to, but couldn't get the pattern matching to work when the string included ["Character"].

Comment: You can simply check for `type(Mytable[MyfirstLvl].Mysecondlvl)`.

Comment: You could set a metatable on `_G` (or whatever table you need to monitor) to notify your code when the variable you're looking for is set, too.

Comment: You can simply check for type(Mytable[MyfirstLvl].Mysecondlvl)...I wish that would work, but it throws an error if any part is not defined.  Thanks anyway

Comment: A *really ugly* solution would be to wrap it in `pcall`...

Comment: Have you considered making `Mytable` local to your addon? You can eliminate the `type(Mytable) == 'table'` check this way.

Comment: The example I gave is not very good.  I'm looking at the savedvariables file from someone else's world of warcraft addon.  I'm trying to change their values or check their values without throwing errors.  I need to make sure the variable is valid.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
if type( ((Mytable or {})[MyfirstLvl] or {}).Mysecondlvl ) == "table"
```

Comment: This is always returning false.  I like the idea and will see if I can expand on it.  Thanks.

Comment: For what I want to do, I think I've found a solution.  Please let me know if their is an easier or more efficient way of doing this. ...Can't add code to this comment so let me try something else.